# Doc.aspx vs doc2.aspx?

Tags: sharepoint-online

When viewing an excel file in the browser, most files redirect to /_layouts/15/doc.aspx?sourcedoc=..., but I've seen some links where the browser is redirected to /_layouts/15/doc**2**.aspx?sourcedoc=...

Anybody know the significance of doc vs doc2? They both work, and they both seem to do the same thing, but perhaps I'm missing something?

I also haven't figured out what conditions will result in the doc2 url.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not anything you should worry about. I tried it and changing in url from doc.aspx to doc2.aspx and nothing happened, just saw my collaboration from another windows, thats all. If I will have more time, I will try digging deeply.